# SQL DATE Comparison within same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datediff

I have a SQL table having below data. I need to compare the date from "Column B" with all the dates present in "Column C" and select the date from "Column C" which is closest to date available in "Column B" but should not be greater than max/min of all dates available in "Column C".

[image]

I am expecting to get result as below. I have tried BETWEEN , DATEDIFF SQL keywords but nothing helped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Comment: Suggest you edit the question to use real column names, to get a better understanding of what you are trying to do.   It would help...

Answer (score 0):

The function to get the difference of two datetimes in SQL Server is `DATEDIFF`. You can tell it to get the difference in minutes, seconds or whatever. Take the absolute value from the difference, as you don't know which of the two datetimes is earlier and which is later. Use `TOP` to get the row with the lowest difference.

```
select top(1) *
from mytable 
order by abs(datediff(second, b, c));
```